# geoserver publishing worldImage(png file) raster data with EPSG3857(mercator projection)

Tags: geoserver

Target: see raster images using openlayers with geoserver wms.

Question: Does it need a .pgw file? 
          What the .pgw content is if using **ESPG:3857**?

Note: let's **suppose** it's a **worldwide image** with position lat(-90:90) and lon(0:360).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it needs a world file (either .pgw or .wld) otherwise GeoServer doesn't know where in the world to put it.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. but I wonder know more about the content of the .pgw file, maybe, how could I generate it.